# How to combine multiple lines in a single text file into one line, in Windows?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I have a multiple standard text files that follow this format, with varying numbers of lines in each file:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
```

I want to merge every line into one, with a space in between each set of characters, so the text file would look as such:

```
Line1 Line2 Line3 Line3
```

...and so on. This needs to work with any given number of lines, due to the fact that each text file contains a different number of lines. My intention is *not* to merge the lines in the text files; I want each text file to remain separate. All the solutions I have found online either don't quite fit this or work exclusively with UNIX. I am running Windows 7. This can be done in Powershell, VBS, Batch, a particular program, doesn't matter, it just needs to work with Windows.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using batch:

```
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%i in ("infile.txt") do @<nul set /p"=%%i ">>"outfile.txt"
>>"outfile.txt" echo.
```

Comment: Endoro, would you know how to do the reverse of this? For example, make one line become multiple lines (each item separate by spaces gets it's own line).

Comment: @Cornbeetle Yes, batch can handle this, but a (input-)line in batch can contain not more than 8191 characters.

Comment: @Endoro Could you help me with a script that would put each word in a sentence on it's own line, so if I have a sentence with 5 words, it would make 5 lines?

Comment: @Endoro Thank you so much! This is much easier than I thought!

Answer (score 8):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
(SET var=)
FOR /f "delims=" %%x IN (list.txt) DO (
CALL SET var=%%var%% %%x
)
SET var=%var:~1%
echo var=%var%=
```

Where list.txt is the file containing your lines and var is the variable into which you want the lines concatenated.

Comment: Thanks alot, that was super helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Using PowerShell give this a try and see if it's what you want:

```
$my_file = "C:\file.txt"
$out_file = "C:\out.txt"
(Get-Content -Path $my_file) -join " " | Set-Content -Path $out_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Install git-scm, cygwin or something else that contains bash, then you can do

```
cat *.txt | tr "\n" " "
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness here's another solution in [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript):

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set infile  = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\infile.txt")
Set outfile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\outfile.txt", 2, True)

If Not infile.AtEndOfStream Then outfile.Write infile.ReadLine
Do Until infile.AtEndOfStream
  outfile.Write " " & infile.ReadLine
Loop

infile.Close
outfile.Close
```

Comment: Good intention, but can we read/write simultaneously in the same file? Also I've got runtime error #54 "Bad file mode" at Line:6 Char:34, and am sure 'cause `outfile` is open with default iomode `ForReading`. But even fixing that, we s'd first read the entire content before writing, else we'll lost the whole file content, agree? ;)

Comment: @PanayotKarabakalov Sorry, copy/paste error. Of course `outfile` was meant to be a different file.

Comment: And I presume it's a typo but was not sure. Glad to see you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
(gc C:\test.txt)  -join " "
```