# Batch script to merge multiple lines

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a text file that contains multiple lines:

```
Mario Rossi 1:17.36 +0.00   1.33    (2) 1.34    (6) 11.46   (2) 1.43    (1) 1.32    (1) 7.55    (1) 3.40    (1) 8.44    (1) 1.21    (19)    12.40   (24)
SWE         1.33    (2) 3.07    (2) 14.53   (2) 16.36   (1) 18.08   (1) 26.03   (1) 29.43   (1) 38.27   (1) 39.48   (1) 52.28   (1)
Alex Haas 1:18.11   +0.35   1.28    (1) 1.35    (10)    11.35   (1) 2.04    (34)    1.42    (6) 8.47    (7) 3.57    (4) 9.26    (2) 1.18    (5) 11.23   (2)
NOR         1.28    (1) 3.03    (1) 14.38   (1) 16.42   (2) 18.24   (2) 27.11   (2) 31.08   (2) 40.34   (2) 41.52   (2) 53.15   (2)
```

I want to combine 2 lines at the time so that the output looks like:

```
Mario Rossi 1:17.36 +0.00   1.33    (2) 1.34    (6) 11.46   (2) 1.43    (1)
SWE                         1.33    (2) 3.07    (2) 14.53   (2) 16.36   (1)
1.32    (1) 7.55    (1) 3.40    (1) 8.44    (1) 1.21    (19)    12.40   (24)
18.08   (1) 26.03   (1) 29.43   (1) 38.27   (1) 39.48   (1)     52.28   (1)

Alex Haas 1:18.11   +0.35   1.28    (1) 1.35    (10)    11.35   (1) 2.04    (34)
NOR                         1.28    (1) 3.03    (1)     14.38   (1) 16.42   (2)
1.42    (6) 8.47    (7) 3.57    (4) 9.26    (2) 1.18    (5) 11.23   (2)
18.24   (2) 27.11   (2) 31.08   (2) 40.34   (2) 41.52   (2) 53.15   (2)
```

All pairs of lines have the same format. There can be many more elements in the lines, so that I need to merge them over more lines (for example output first 12 elements of first line, then first 12 elements of second line, then next 12 elements of first line, then next 12 elements of second line, and so on, until the end of the line is reached).

So far I could only find solutions where the multiple lines are concatenated, where it was not necessary to mix the content of the lines ([How to combine multiple lines in a single text file into one line, in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459131/how-to-combine-multiple-lines-in-a-single-text-file-into-one-line-in-windows) or [Batch - Combine two lines and add comma to reformat txt to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356343/batch-combine-two-lines-and-add-comma-to-reformat-txt-to-csv)). So I'm stuck with the following piece of code, which I don't know how to complete:

```
@echo off
set _inputfile=myfile
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set evenflag=1
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (%_inputfile%.txt) do set x1=!x2! && set x2=%%x && (
set /a evenflag^^=1 && if !evenflag!==1 (
    rem how to process !x1! and !x2! to get desired output?
))
pause
```

Comment: this is a bit confusing.. 5 elements of first line, then 5 elements of second line and there after second 5 elements of 1st line again?

Comment: The first tokens of the lines should be treated slightly different, since they include the name. So in the expected output, first line with first 12 tokens of input line 1, second line with first 9 tokens of input line 2, third line with next 12 tokens of input line 1, fourth line with next 12 tokens of input line 2.
Input lines can be even longer, so in the output I would like the fifth line with the tokens 25-36 of input line 1, sixth line with tokens 22-33 of input line 2, and so on.

Comment: hmmm.. it will be getting a little complicated to achieve a decent result with something like batch commands. Why not consider a proper scripting language like perl perhaps?

Comment: I never used perl, that's why...if nobody can suggest a meaningful way through batch script, I'll try perl!

Answer (score 1):

As [Gerhard Barnard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7818749/gerhard-barnard) suggested, a batch script for this purpose would get very complicated. I solved my problem easily with the following Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $elementtoprint = 12; #how many elements per line are printed in the output
local $" = "\t"; #set tab as default separator when printing an array

open my $info, "input.txt" or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while ( my $line1 = <$info> )
{
    defined(my $line2 = <$info>) or last;
    #convert strings into arrays
    my @tab1 = split(/\s+/, $line1);
    my @tab2 = split(/\s+/, $line2);

    #handle first output lines (with people's names) differently
    my @subtab1 = splice (@tab1,0,$elementtoprint);
    my @subtab2 = shift(@tab2);
    my @subtab3 = splice (@tab2,0,$elementtoprint-4);
    print "@subtab1 \n";
    print "@subtab2 \t\t\t\t@subtab3 \n";

    while(@tab1&&@tab2)
    {
        my @subtab1 = splice(@tab1,0,$elementtoprint);
        my @subtab2 = splice(@tab2,0,$elementtoprint);
        print "@subtab1 \n";
        print "@subtab2 \n";
    }
    print "\n";
}

close $info;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code do what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "spaces28=                            "
set "line1="
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if not defined line1 (
      set "line1=%%a"
   ) else (
      set "line2=%%a"
      call :SplitLines
   )
)
goto :EOF


:SplitLines

set "header=1"
:nextPart

   for /F "tokens=12*" %%a in ("%line1%") do (
      if "%%b" equ "" (set "head=%line1%") else set "head=!line1:%%b=!"
      set "line1=%%b"
   )
   set /P "=%head%" < nul
   echo/

   if %header% equ 1 (
      for /F "tokens=9*" %%a in ("%line2%") do (
         if "%%b" equ "" (set "head=%line2%") else set "head=!line2:%%b=!"
         for /F "tokens=1*" %%c in ("!head!") do (
            set "head=%%c%spaces28%"
            set "head=!head:~0,28!%%d"
         )
         set "line2=%%b"
      )
      set "header=0"
   ) else (
      for /F "tokens=12*" %%a in ("%line2%") do (
         if "%%b" equ "" (set "head=%line2%") else set "head=!line2:%%b=!"
         set "line2=%%b"
      )
   )
   set /P "=%head%" < nul
   echo/

if defined line1 goto nextPart
echo/

exit /B
```

Output example:

```
Mario Rossi 1:17.36 +0.00   1.33    (2) 1.34    (6) 11.46   (2) 1.43    (1) 
SWE                         1.33    (2) 3.07    (2) 14.53   (2) 16.36   (1) 
1.32    (1) 7.55    (1) 3.40    (1) 8.44    (1) 1.21    (19)    12.40   (24)
18.08   (1) 26.03   (1) 29.43   (1) 38.27   (1) 39.48   (1) 52.28   (1)

Alex Haas 1:18.11   +0.35   1.28    (1) 1.35    (10)    11.35   (1) 2.04    (34)    
NOR                         1.28    (1) 3.03    (1) 14.38   (1) 16.42   (2) 
1.42    (6) 8.47    (7) 3.57    (4) 9.26    (2) 1.18    (5) 11.23   (2)
18.24   (2) 27.11   (2) 31.08   (2) 40.34   (2) 41.52   (2) 53.15   (2)
```

Comment: This works for the exact input I gave (or if the input lines have a multiple of 12 tokens), but if the input lines have a different number of tokens, then this gets stuck in a loop. I was able to solve my problem using Perl.